# Read data from DataGridView and save to database

Tags: c#

I want to save the data from datagrid to database, I used the following code.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView_displaycount.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into StocktransferlocationDetails(date,stocktransferlocation,Itemcode,Count,Description) values(@date,@stocktransferlocation,@Itemcode,@Count,@Description) ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",System.DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocktransferlocation", comboBox_locationfrom.SelectedText+"-"+comboBox_locationto.SelectedText);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemcode", r.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", r.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", r.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Here my problem is the datagrid contains the empty row at the last. So I write the data and when it comes to the empty row it throws me an error.

Comment: Are you loading this Data into a DataTable at any point. What is the Datasource for your Data Grid? I wouldn't do this in the same manner. As your opening a connection and executing your command for every row in the data grid. If your using a Data Adapter, you can update the DataTable quite easily. If you can provide some more info It will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a **foreach** loop here?

Use a **for** loop like:

```
for(int i=0; i<dataGridView_displaycount.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
   //Your code
}
```

This should be an easy solution to solve your problem rather than any other code changes.

**Update:** Adding the gridview data to the database:

```
for(int i=0; i< dataGridView_displaycount.Rows.Count-1;i++)
 {
    Strquery= @"Insert into StocktransferlocationDetails(date,stocktransferlocation,....) values (" 
                + System.DateTime.Now +", "+ comboBox_locationfrom.SelectedText+"-"+comboBox_locationto.SelectedText +"," 
                + dataGridView_displaycount.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value +".......);";
    cmd.CommandText = Strquery;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: hi, Cdeez, 1 more doubt, how to assign the value to database in the code part. example sample plz

Comment: @Cdeez:you code does not read last row.you wrote i<count-1 so if we have 3 rows the maximum value of i can be 1 and its not correct

Comment: @Arash Suppose you have 4 rows in which last row is empty. The OP want to read 3 rows excluding the 4th empty row. `Count` will give you `4`. Now i<4 as per YOUR assumption will read `0,1,2,3 rows` which means all the four rows are read. So it should be `i<count-1`. Hope its clear.

Comment: If you have 1000 rows your opening 1000 connections and executing 1000 commands.

Comment: Derek: It would be a  better idea to tell that to the OP. I have just given a solution for avoiding reading the last row.

Comment: @Cdeez: u r correct, using rows.count-1 which does not read the last empty row, i need the code how to assign the value to database

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use for Like This :

```
For(int row=0;row<datagridview.rows.count;row++)

{
//Do Work
}
```

Comment: @Cdeez:No,count returns number of rows,for example if we have 3 rows,it return 3,not 2.so i wrote row<datagridview.rows.count because of work with all of the exist rows

Comment: Please see the comment in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for nulls as shown in the below piece of code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView_displaycount.Rows)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into StocktransferlocationDetails(date,stocktransferlocation,Itemcode,Count,Description) values(@date,@stocktransferlocation,@Itemcode,@Count,@Description) ", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", System.DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocktransferlocation", comboBox_locationfrom.SelectedText + "-" + comboBox_locationto.SelectedText);

    if (r.Cells[1] != null && r.Cells[1].Value != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemcode", r.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    if (r.Cells[2] != null && r.Cells[2].Value != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", r.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    if (r.Cells[3] != null && r.Cells[3].Value != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", r.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for last row:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", r.Cells[3].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
```